# Force refresh the interface in Qt Quick

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am building a Qt Quick QML application, and one button launches a process that takes a while to run.  I'd like to let the user know that the program is actually doing something, but if I do something like this:

```
Button {
    text: "Click me"
    onClicked: {
        text = "Loading..."
        backend.longRunningFunction()
        text = "Click me"
     }
}
```

When I click the button, the GUI freezes while `backend.longRunningFunction()` runs, then returns to normal.  But the text never changes; it always reads "Click me".

Is there a way I can force the UI to update in the `onClicked` function, something like `qApp.processEvents()`?

Comment: Read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#timing-considerations

Comment: May be [WorkerScript](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can force a GUI update in C++ by calling

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

first thing in your longRunningFunction.

You can make it more general by making a c++ function in the same class like

```
void Backend::updateUI() 
{
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
}
```

and call it from your onClicked as

```
onClicked: {
    button1.text = "Loading..."
    backend.updateUI()
    backend.longRunningFunction()
    button1.text = "Click me"
}
```

The recommended way from QT is to spawn a QThread of actual long-running part of longRunningFunction, and send a done signal from that thread to update button1.text.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
Button {
id: button1
text: "Click me"
onClicked: {
    button1.text = "Loading..."
    backend.longRunningFunction()
    button1.text = "Click me"
 }}
```